# is there any way regex python if space exist match if doesn't match without space?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, python-re

i am trying to make a script that translate java code to python code, so i tried this :

```
from re import sub

java_code = """
for(i=1; i>10; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
"""
#//////////////////////////////////////
schema = r"""
for\((.+);\s+(.+);\s+(.+)\) {
(.+)
}
"""
#//////////////////////////////////////
final_form = r"""
\1
while(\2):
\4
    \3"""
#//////////////////////////////////////
py_code = sub(schema, final_form, java_code)
print(py_code)
```

then when the for loop is inside another block it doesn't work
as exemple if the for loop is inside another forloop or if it has tab space it won't work

```
java_code = """
    for(i=1; i>10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
"""
```

is there any solution to work if there is a tab space and either if there is no tab space ?

Comment: Use `\s*` to match optional whitespace.

Comment: What is "tap space"?

Comment: Java syntax is a tiny bit more complex than this. Forget regex.

Comment: I would have thought that you would find it easier to have a variable `leadingSpace` that you increment at each `{ ` and decrement at each `} `. When the compiler reads a script it parses it character by character, group by group by group, line by line. Your code translater should work the same way?